# C# , crystal report , phpmyadmin , error while choose procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

i'm using C# and phpmyadmin db, when i created procedure 'report_patient' and try to use it with crystal report, by click on database Expert option ,then i create the connection then choose the procedure it's show this message :

" Database Connector Error: 'HY000: [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.5-10.4.28-MariaDB]Support for schemas is disabled by NO_SCHEMA option, but non-empty schema is specified.' "

and that's my stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `report_patient`(IN 
`name_patient` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SELECT patient_id,patient_name,patient_sex,datelog from patient
WHERE patient_name LIKE CONCAT('%',name_patient,'%');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

it's supposed to show the database Fields without any errors